# Java libGDX Textures render outside of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to make an android game by the help of libGDX. My game is in portrait mode.
Bird texture is rendering via for loop with a random OffSet. Sometimes my birds render outside of the screen. Here is my code for rendering:

```
                if (birdX>Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) {
                    birdY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;

                    birdX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-birdX-numberOfBirds*distanceBird;
                    bird2X = bird2X + numberOfBirds*distanceBird+Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

                    birdOffSet1[i] = (random.nextFloat()-0.5f)*(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-200);
                    birdOffSet2[i] = (random.nextFloat()-0.5f)*(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-200);
                } else {
                    birdX = birdX + cloudVelocity + 2;
                    bird2X = bird2X - cloudVelocity -2;
                }
                batch.draw(bird1,birdX,birdY+birdOffSet1[i],Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/18);
                batch.draw(bird2,bird2X,birdY+birdOffSet2[i],Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/18);
            }
```

**And values of the variables are:**

numberOfBirds is 1,

distanceBird is 0

float[] birdOffSet1 = new float[numberOfBirds];

float[] birdOffSet2 = new float[numberOfBirds];

float birdX=-100;

float birdY=0;

float bird2X=1100;

I don't want to render my birds outside of the screen randomly. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Instead of `graphics.getWidth()` (and height), you should be using the camera's `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight`. These are the actual bounds of the view in your game's coordinates. And you need to take into account the camera's position. For example, if the camera is at x=0 and y=0, the left edge of the view is `-camera.viewportWidth / 2f`. But if the camera is a `x=viewportWidth/2f`, then the left edge of the view is at x=0.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it @Tenfour04